# What does "Process finished with exit code 1" in intellij-idea?

Tags: java, minecraft

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
01:16:25.288 [Client thread] ERROR net.minecraft.client.resources.ResourceIndex - Can't find the resource index file: assets\indexes\1.12.json
Exception in thread "Client thread" 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I do not know what to do

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error; you can set the `StatusLogger.level` to `Trace`, or try putting the main method in a try-catch block.

But you probably didn't configure log4j2 correctly, configuration file can help.

Comment: can I go into more detail, I'm new to this field

Comment: @MintyX: if you want to provide additional info, please [edit] your question and include it in text (as I commented on your question). Don't just paste screenshots here.

Answer (score 0):

To configure log4j2, create a file called log4j2.xml on your classpath with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

See also https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

The exit codes are usually called by the System.exit() method which takes status as a parameter. These codes tell about the status of termination. Each value from -2^31 up to 2^31-1 can be used as an exit code. But there are a few standardized codes.

Edit:
Here are some examples:

- 0 -> Indicates **successful** termination
- 1 -> Indicates unsuccessful termination
- -1 -> Indicates unsuccessful termination with Exception

Be aware that **any non-zero** value indicates an **failure** termination

Comment: In fact, _Each value from -2^31 up to 2^31-1 can be used as an exit code. But there are a few standardized codes:_ it is more 0-255 in practice : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418784/what-is-the-min-and-max-values-of-exit-codes-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that LOG4J2 does not fail in case of misconfiguration; the error you get from it may simply be because the configuration file is provided but does not exists.

In this cases, LOG4J2 produce information on its StatusLogger to help diagnose a logging configuration issue.

You should check with your Minecraft mod/whatever what's the following resource:

```
Can't find the resource index file: assets\indexes\1.12.json
Exception in thread "Client thread" 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Because it is most likely to be the culprit here.